# Using 12/3 wire to run a different outlets in a kitchen

Tags: electrical

I am running 12/3 wire into 3 kitchen outlets. In my panel box I had an electican deciate two 20amp breakers for the red hot wire and black hot wire. I have connected the black wire to 2 different outlets and are working great. I need another outlet using the red hot wire. So, my question is I know that the red is hot so do I just connect it to the other reds and continue my circuit to the third outlet? Then do I also connect to the 2nd outlet white and neutral wires on the last outlet to finish the circuit?

Comment: A more common approach is to wire the red to one hot on each outlet, and the black to the other, **removing the tie** between the hots - that way one half of each duplex is on red, one half is on black. And yes, the breaker should be a double, or singles joined with a listed tie, as Ed says.

Comment: Since kitchen and the seperate circuit is the last outlet in the daisy chain, you will either need to make each outlet it's own GFCI receptacle or use a double pole GFCI breaker.  Since outlet 3 uses a shared neutral you won't be able to GFCI protect outlet 2 using outlet 1's GFCI.

Comment: Each of your neutrals needs to be pigtailed (unless they are downstream of a 120V GFCI outlet).  The concept is that removing a device should not sever the neutral for any side of the circuit.   Also, the two 20A breakers need to have a "handle tie" between them so they switch off together; as an alternate you can use a 2-pole 240 breaker.

Answer (score 2):

You have a multi wire branch circuit. You are correct that the reds go to 1 set of outlets with the white and ground from the point you brought the black, white & ground. The first outlet in each string should be a GFCI for all counter top outlets 2014 NEC 210.8.A.6. The handles should be tied with a listed snap on tie or a double pole breaker to be fully code compliant.